# Mysql: combination of Group by , order , max. Get maximum value of grouped set and apply a condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

There is a table reservations in mysql database in the below format.

```
id | customer_id | user_id | date_booked
1  | 1           | 1       | 2012-11-5
```

I want to get the count of customers for a particular User. so I wrote query

```
select count(*), user_id, customer_id,date_booked from reservations where user_id=1 group by customer_id
```

This fetches results in desired way. But date_booked , I get the first value recorded. i.e., If there are 4 records for a customer with id 2 , It fetches 1st record's date_booked value. I want the latest value , So I improved the query like below

```
select count(*), user_id, customer_id,max(date_booked) from reservations where user_id=1 group by customer_id
```

This fetches highest date recorded. This is still not the result set I want to fetch. I want the latest date but that should be less that current date (today).

Is there a way to write condition like this

```
max(date_booked)<date(now())
```

I want to fetch max date but less than today. I want to achieve this in CakePHP. If someone can help with Query I can write it cakePHP format.

*Please improve the question if necessary.*

Comment: How about adding the condition in where? `where user_id=1 AND date_booked<now() group by customer_id`

Comment: there is a condition user_id=1. But I cannot use date_booked<now() as I want to get the count of all records irrespective of date but date_booked column which is immediately less than today. But your comment is helpful in other way I need to check if that is ok to fetch count of values less than today. Any Idea how to achieve without that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  count(*),a.user_id,a.customer_id,
   IF(max(a.date_booked)>now(), b.date_booked, max(a.date_booked)) as date_booked
from reservations a left join 
   (select max(date_booked) as date_booked,customer_id 
        from reservations where date_booked < now() group by customer_id) b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
where a.user_id=1 
group by customer_id
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. Now i am decoding what you have done here :p . trying to learn that way. Thank you sel

Comment: Do you mind breaking  above query and explaining it? It helps me to write query myself and also it helps if someone else want to apply the similar query in different situation?  

Thank you

Comment: The select count is normal query like yours. The reason i did a left join is to get the max date that fit your requirement (ie datebooked< now). In this way, we will get a result of `count ,user_id,customer_id,a.datebooked,b.datebooked`. `b.datebooked` is selected based on the condition < now. There is possibility a.datebooked could be > now(). This is when `IF(max(a.date_booked)>now() ...`  came in.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select count(*), user_id, customer_id,max(date_booked) 
from reservations 
where user_id=1 
and date_booked<date(now())
group by customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe . sel suggested the same , please read my reply to above comment

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*), 
       rs.user_id, 
       rs.customer_id,
       CASE WHEN max(rs.date_booked)<date(now()) then max(rs.date_booked) 
           else (select max(r.date_booked) from reservations r where r.user_id=rs.user_id 
                  and r.date_booked<date(now()) and r.customer_id=rs.customer_id
                  ) end as latestdate
from reservations rs 
where rs.user_id=1 
group by rs.customer_id
```

Comment: Wow! I just learned how to write conditions in Mysql . Thanks for that. But query in else conditions fails . error is "Error code 1242, SQL state 21000: Subquery returns more than 1 row"
If that returns more than one row how to do we know it uses customer id we used in parent query? Any Idea?